# CSS-based hover menu getting hidden in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

On this site: http://chezkoop.ca/united the drop down menus are hidden behind the slider (on the homepage) and the page titles (on the other pages) in IE7 (haven't checked IE6 and I'm not supporting it).

I feel like I have tried every possible combination of `z:index: X` and `position: relative` as various posts around the internet have suggested. Nothing has worked and I am going crazy!

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Adrian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you've read the various posts explaining this IE7 bug, so I'm not going to link to them.

Here's a way to fix it:

- On `#slider-slides`, remove `position: relative`.
- On `#menu-menu`, add `z-index: 3000`.
- On `#nav`, add `z-index: 4000`.

Here's a live page with a version of the tweaks above that works in IE7: http://jsbin.com/ixefa3

You don't need to use such large `z-index` values. I just picked convenient and high numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works a charm.

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with it for a bit in IE Dev Tools, i realized your problem - make sure you've got the z-index set on ALL the elements - the picture and all its parent containers, the menu and all ITS parent containers until the two meet. hope that helps...if not i can try to clarify.